# Select all checkbox doesn't work anymore after table reload JQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, refresh, reload

I have a table with some products and near each product I have a checkbox which has as value the product id. On top of the page I have a Select All checkbox which selects/deselects all the other checkboxes using the following jquery function:

```
$("#selectall").change(function(){
    $(".check").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Anyway, I have a "Delete selected" button which removes from my table the checked products. This button refreshes only my table, not the entire page, in an ajax function, using:

```
$("#prodTable").load( "../product #prodTable" );
```

My problem is that after I refresh the table, the "Select All" checkbox doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for attaching event to dynamically added dom:

```
$("#prodTable").on('change','#selectall',function(){
 $(".check").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#selectall").change(function(){
    $(".check").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

Put above code after refresh table because its assign that event to dynamically added checkbox.